# Obligatory DateTime issues with C# - Determine if UtcNow is between given time span only

Tags: c#

I have a situation in which I need to set up a re-occuring time span (for this example, 6 PM - 6 AM is the span of time)

Date is not relevent to this. It is presumed to be a check every single day.

I am having trouble wrapping my head around how to do it because using `DateTime.UtcNow` does yield me the right time, but it does not yield the right day. However using `DateTime.MinValue` does not yield the current time. And I was not able to set the Date manually. I have explored the other posts on stack overflow, and I'm just misunderstanding something, I think.. but this is my paltry code at the moment...

```
var start = DateTime.MinValue.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(18, 0, 0));
            var end = DateTime.MinValue.Date.Add(new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0));
            var timezone = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.GetUtcOffset(start);
            var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
            now.Date = DateTime.MinValue;

            // is right now greater than 6pm est?
            Console.WriteLine(start.TimeOfDay < now);
            Console.WriteLine(end < DateTime.UtcNow);
            Console.WriteLine(start.ToShortTimeString());
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay);
            Console.WriteLine(timezone.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: now.Date = DateTime.MinValue;  // Error: read-only property

Comment: Yes, I stated in the question that trying to set the date directly did not work. Forgive me, that line should have been commented out.

Comment: 6PM - 6AM wouldn't be in one date as such, not sure what you are looking for

Comment: If you are using UTC date, but local (if you are saying that UTC time is not correct) time, what time is it between the end of a day in UTC and start a new day in local time, ha?

Comment: Yes, I know 6PM - 6AM wouldn't be in one date. It is a required evaluation regardless. I have to find a way to make it work.

Comment: As for the UTC thing, I always fetch time as UTC no matter what. I am assuming that all times and values related will be UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure as what you want to achieve but for a check won't something like this do for you

```
DateTime dt3 = DateTime.UtcNow;
if(dt3.Hour <= 6 || dt3.Hour >=18)//24 hr format
   MessageBox.Show("6PM - 6AM range");// UTC will have only one time and should get satisfied irrespective of date
```

Comment: I actually had to flip the operators (change it to >= 6 and <= 18) but this did give me the correct evaluation! Still doing some testing to see if it will work all the time.

Comment: Inverting the statements works right now but I think that is because my math is wrong. I need to rethink the actual numbers entered...

Comment: Ok. This makes sense now. Here is what was going wrong. `UtcNow` would, as expected, return the UTC time. However `6` in UTC is not 6 AM locally. So in truth, the code was returning the __correct__ data, but my brain was thinking in __local__ data. I've adjusted the numbers to standardize on UTC. The only thing that leaves to question is DaylightSavings...

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is between midnight UTC and 6AM UTC or between 6PM UTC and midnight UTC the following day, you're going to have to combine two clauses:

```
bool IsNowInTimeSpan = (DateTime.UtcNow >= DateTime.Date && DateTime.UtcNow <= DateTime.Date.AddHours(6)) ||
                       (DateTime.UtcNow >= DateTime.Date.AddHours(18) && DateTime.UtcNow <= DateTime.Date.AddDays(1));
```